# Get objects out of scala interpreter

Tags: scala, interpreter

I spent hours investigating one topic. I am definitely out of my depth here. What I want is to run the scala interpreter programmatically and be able to extract object values from the interpreter. for example, if I send

```
val a = 1
val b = a + 1
```

I want to be able to read out b as an Int, not just a string printed out like

```
b = 2
```

The source code is dense. So far I don't see any part which would allow such an extraction. Any experts here who can give me a tip or tell me this is utter nonsense?

How do I get typed objects out of the scala interpreter between sessions?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? What do you hope to achieve? There may be a better way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Use JSR 223.

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.7 [...]

scala> import javax.script._
import javax.script._

scala> val engine = (new ScriptEngineManager).getEngineByName("scala")
engine: javax.script.ScriptEngine = scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain@4233e892

scala> engine.eval("val a = 1")
res0: Object = 1

scala> engine.eval("val b = a + 1")
res1: Object = 2

scala> engine.eval("b").asInstanceOf[Int]
res2: Int = 2
```

Comment: this is cool, but at the end, its just printing some text on the screen. I don't get the b object.

Comment: Yes, you do. That's what `engine.eval("b")` gives you.

Comment: I tried val engine = (new ScriptEngineManager).getEngineByName("scala") inside spark-shell, which is also a scala repl, but got null back. How to find out the name of the engine?

Comment: Scala's JSR 223 support wasn't added until Scala 2.11. Spark uses Scala 2.10 (though I think a version based on 2.11 is available? not really sure).